# How figure out calling function setTimeout function at react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a react functional component.

Here is i have `getData` function, with this function i'm getting some data from api and then if data have i wan't to call `anotherFunc();`, But i wan't to do that after 3 second. I tried to put there setTimeout function but it's worked directly not wait 3 second. What i need to do?

```
function Hello(props) {

  anotherFunc = () => {
    console.log('hello');
  } 

  const getData = () => {
    let data = {
      id: 1
    }
    axios.post(baseUrl, data).then(res => {
      if (res.data) {
        setTimeout(() => {
           anotherFunc();
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
  }


  return <h1>Something</h1>;
}

export default Hello;
```

Comment: How are you calling `getData` function? Are you calling it from an event handler or an effect? Can we see the code for that?

Comment: i'm calling it on eventHandler at onClick on some button.

Comment: I tried to replicate an example similar to yours and it works properly (open the console): https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-architecture-3qikq. You might have a bug somewhere else (maybe in the click handler).